# Javascript scrollIntoView() doesn't place <details> at top of page

Tags: javascript, html

I use the HTML details/summary on my page:

```
<details id="_1" onclick="closeDetails('_1')">
            <summary>Title 1</summary>
            ...content...
</details>
<details id="_2" onclick="closeDetails('_2')">
            <summary>Title 2</summary>
            ...content...
</details>
```

I have this Javascript to close the previously opened detail and to place the newly opened detail at the top of the screen:

```
function closeDetails(y) {
for (i=1; i<31; i++) {
        x = "_"+i;
        if (y != x){ document.getElementById(x).open = false;}
        document.getElementById(y).scrollIntoView();
        }
}
```

This works except that the Titles within the details tag appear just off the top of the screen. Is there a solution?

Comment: There is a good docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView . 
You can use `elem.scrollIntoView({block:center})`

Comment: That's not exactly what I wanted but it will do. Thank you.